# Same controller action, but different redirect based on submitted param/view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, redirect, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

I have a strange problem in Rails 4 that concerns the update action for one of my models.

There are 2 views that enable the user to edit a product: The standard `edit_product` view and an additional barebones `edit_product_images` view that is accessed from a desktop application and doesn't provide any additional application layout.

Both views lead to the update action when their form is submitted. However while I want the full web browser view to return to the product#show view after saving, the stripped down version should just reload the `edit_product_images` page once the update action is completed.

Of course I could create another action that is very similar to the existing update action but just uses a different redirect. However that seems very redundant. Instead I intended to pass an additional `:same_page => 1` param through a hidden field when the `edit_product_images` form is submitted.

In my update action I have the following code to check if `params[:same_page] == "1"` is true for this update action:

**products_controller.rb**

```
def update

  respond_to do |format|

    if @product.update(product_params)

      format.html do
        if params[:same_page] == "1"
          render action: "edit_product_images", layout: false
        else
          redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.'
        end  
      end

      format.json { head :no_content }

    else
      format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end

end
```

Unfortunately though the if `params[:same_page] == 1` clause always seems to return false so that I'm just redirected to the `product#show` view. I checked the logs and the parameter is passed on form submit. Why would my if statement fail?

What am I missing here? And is there a better way to handle this functionality? After all I just want different redirects based on the original view the action is triggered from - the additional parameter just seemed to be the easiest way to achieve this. I'm open to better solutions though.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you share the server log generated when you submit the form in `edit_product_images` page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If hidden field is passed from the form then it may be nested within `product` hash. 
As you have not shared the params hash in question I can only suggest you to use `params[:product][:same_page]` instead of `params[:same_page]` and see if it works out for you.

You can check the `params` hash in server log and see how exactly `same_page` is passed in it.

Comment: Of course, I can't believe I've been running around in circles while missing such an obvious mistake. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Try out  `if params[:same_page] == true`  this may solve your problem

Comment: It doesn't work. As explained in a response to Oscar's answer params are always passed as string, in this case "1", which doesn't equal true. Even a value like true itself would be converted to a string once it's used as a parameter.

Answer (score -2):

Try `params[:same_page] == '1'` instead of `params[:same_page] == "1"`

Comment: I tried, but already learned that parameters are always passed as strings, which is why you have to compare the param to "1", or "true" instead of true to give another example.

Comment: True that! Check my edited answer. Basically single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: And What difference is it going to make: '1' vs "1"?

Comment: For some strange reasons it has made a difference for me in the past? :/

Comment: I don't think so. You might have misjudged something. '1' and "1" are exactly same. Try `"1" == '1'` in rails console.